# Problems implementing simple algorithm using list

Tags: python

so I got this code:

```
from random import randint

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5]
enemy = 2
# it's going to be randint(1, 5)
print(enemy)
user = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 5: ")) # user input 1
user = n-1

if enemy == mylist[user+1] or enemy == mylist[user+3]:
    print("You win!")
elif enemy == mylist[user]:
    print ("It's a draw")
else:
    print ("You lose")
```

Okay, yay user won since the algorithm for wining is: you win (your input *n*) against numbers *n+1* and *n+3*. So if user input is 1 (mylist[0]) he will win against 2 (mylist[user+1]) and 4 (mylist[user+3]). But the issue is when user will input number 5 I will get.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there a way to pass it?

```
user = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 5: ")) # user input 5
user = n-1 # 4

if enemy == mylist[user+1] or enemy == mylist[user+3]: 
"""what you can do so that the mylist[4+1] won't equal index mylist[5] which 
is out of list range but instead it will go back to mylist[0]?""" 

    print("You win!")
elif enemy == mylist[user]:
    print ("It's a draw")
else:
    print ("You loose")
```

Thank you in advance, I'm really stuck.

Comment: you could use `mod`. like `mylist[(user+1) % 5]`. Note thought that this approach will also handle inputs like `23` which will become `3`. This might or **might not** be desired.

Comment: Defining `n` somewhere might also help tracking the problem

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thank you for the reply. Modulo will handle number 5.

6(user input +1)%5=1 
8(user input +3)%5=3
And that is correct.
But for let's say 3 it will go:
4(user input +1)%3 = 1 that is correct
and 
6(user input +3)%3 = 0. It's false sicne the winning numbers for 3 are 1 and 4.